# strange error in my Animation Drawable

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, logcat

A strange error when trying to start `Activity`.

i think the error in my `Animation Drawable`

**LogCat:**

```
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.MalekAlrwily.BasicVaccinations/com.MalekAlrwily.BasicVaccinations.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at com.MalekAlrwily.BasicVaccinations.Main.onCreate(Main.java:15)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  ... 11 more
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  ... 23 more
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:695)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:901)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:837)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2087)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3293)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:453)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:242)
    12-31 06:37:45.138: E/AndroidRuntime(922):  ... 26 more
```

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="@drawable/animation"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Main" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`AnimationDrawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/begin1" android:duration="3000" />
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/begin2" android:duration="3000" />
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/begin3" android:duration="3000" />
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/begin4" android:duration="3000" />
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/begin5" android:duration="3000" />
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/begin6" android:duration="3000" />
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/begin7" android:duration="3000" />
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/begin8" android:duration="3000" />
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/begin9" android:duration="3000" />
</animation-list>
```

Comment: How big are the images in your animation drawable and how many items are there. Can you put the contents of your animation drawable in the question?

Comment: Yeah waht is the physical properties of these images? Width, Height, color space?

Comment: Width : 768 , Height : 1280.

Comment: That will do it :) And I am guessing 32bit color, so 4 bytes * (768 * 1280) pixels is the amount of space needed to just hold one of these images in uncompressed form in memory. I would either use smaller images with a more specialized color palette or use a different approach

Comment: how to upload image ?

Comment: Um it's your image. Looking at the image isn't going to change the answer to this question. It requires too much memory just given the characteristics of one frame of the AnimationDrawable

Answer (score 0):

Looks like whatever is in your Animation Drawable definition is too much memory to decode and sequence. The idea is that it loads up all the items and make them in an array and swaps them in and out of the scene according to the timing specified for each frame.

If this all can't fit into memory, it's probably better to either do this on your own with some sort of handler or better yet just encode a movie with the specified frames at the corresponding images and play the animation through a video codec.

Comment: Yeah it's your code, you can do what you need :) Checkout MediaPlayer OnCompletionListener. Then just restart your video. The tricky parts come when you need the background to be transparent because it is not being played over a solid background

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Your drawable images may be too large. Better you should reduce the size of images.